# data in foreach used in update query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach, nested-loops

This is my code:

```
session_start();
/* loops through each row in the global $_SESSION variable which
contains the array and uses the $value to GET the data in the text
boxes and output them */

// studevent_result = 
foreach ($_SESSION['arrayNameResult'] as $value) {
    $studResult = $_GET[$value];
    echo $studResult;
    echo "<br>";
}

// result_postion = 
foreach ($_SESSION['arrayNamePosition'] as $value) {
    $studPosition = $_GET[$value];
    echo $studPosition;
    echo "<br>";
}

echo "<br>";

// stud_id = 
foreach ($_SESSION['arrayId'] as $value) {
    echo $value;
    echo "<br>";
}

// UPDATE query, this will update the studevent_result and result_position
// column in the database for the specific stud_id.
$updateQuery = "
    UPDATE result
    SET studevent_result = '00:20:33',
        result_position = '6'
    WHERE result.stud_id = '12'
";
$updateRow = mysqli_query($conn, $updateQuery);
```

I use `$_SESSION` variables which all store an array. I extract the results of these arrays using foreach loops.

In `$updateQuery`, I want to make `studevent_result` = to the results of my first foreach loop above, `result_position` = to the results of the second foreach loop above and the `result.stud_id` = to the results of the third foreach loop above. How can I modify my code to make this work?

..............................................................................

EDIT:

So after me editing the code my code now looks like this:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['arrayNameResult'] as $value) {
$studResult = $_GET[$value];
        foreach ($_SESSION['arrayNamePosition'] as $data) {
            $studPosition = $_GET[$data];
    foreach ($_SESSION['arrayId'] as $idValue) {
echo $idValue;
$updateQuery = "
    UPDATE result
    SET studevent_result = '$studResult',
        result_position = '$studPosition'
    WHERE result.stud_id = '$idValue'
";
$updateRow = mysqli_query($conn, $updateQuery);
            }
        }
    }
```

I nested the foreach loops. But the problem now is that for the last foreach loop in the nested loops, $idValue in the query only uses the last element in the array `$_SESSION['arrayId']`. How can I fix this to loop throught the whole array, so that the query uses all the values in the array?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the link between the various elements in the various arrays? For example, is the first element of `$_SESSION['arrayNameResult']` linked to the first element of `$_SESSION['arrayNamePosition']` and the first element of `$_SESSION['arrayId']`? Do all three arrays have the exact same number of elements?

Comment: I am not entirely sure here but looks like you need nested foreach loops with the query being executed in the inner most foreach.

Comment: @Technoh yes all three arrays have the exact same number of elements and the first element of all three arrays link and so on.

Comment: @Maximus2012 What would the syntax to that be like?

Answer (score 1):

```
for( $counter = 0; $counter < count( $_SESSION['arrayNameResult'] ); $counter++ ) {
    $studevent_result = current( $_SESSION['arrayNameResult'] );
    $result_position = current( $_SESSION['arrayNamePosition'] );
    $stud_id = current( $_SESSION['arrayId'] );
    next( $_SESSION['arrayNameResult'] );
    next( $_SESSION['arrayNamePosition'] );
    next( $_SESSION['arrayId'] );

    // UPDATE query, this will update the studevent_result and result_position
    // column in the database for the specific stud_id.
    $updateQuery = "
        UPDATE
            result
        SET
            studevent_result = '$studevent_result',
            result_position = '$result_position'
        WHERE
            result.stud_id = '$stud_id'
    ";

    $updateRow = mysqli_query($conn, $updateQuery);
}
```

Note that it would be more secure and just best practice to create a prepared statement and use `prepare` and `bind_param` on it.

**Edit** if your `$_SESSION` arrays use numeric indices then you can simply do this:

```
$studevent_result = $_SESSION['arrayNameResult'][$counter];
$result_position = $_SESSION['arrayNamePosition'][$counter];
$stud_id = $_SESSION['arrayId'][$counter];
```

and skip the `next` calls.

Comment: this did not work for me for some reason, it does not update the database with the values I want.

Comment: What happens? Any errors? If you `var_dump` the query is it complete? If you try the same query in phpmyadmin what happens?

Comment: There are no errors, its just that what ever i enter into the three arrays, that value does not get updated into the database, it gives different values. `var_dump` gives the output `bool(true)`

Comment: If the `var_dump`ed query string does not update the value in the database then I guess this solution can't help you, sorry.